# The pywin32 library is not working for me. Python 3.11.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome

I am making a program that displays the saved passwords in Google in cmd. And for some reason the win32crypt library doesn't work for me. My Python version is 3.11.2. When you type in cmd (pip install pywin32) it displays (Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (306)) but the library still doesn't work.
Help me please.

code

```
import os
import json
import base64
import sqlite3
import win32crypt
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import shutil
from datetime import timezone, datetime, timedelta


def get_encryption_key():
    local_state_path = os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"],
                                    "AppData", "Local", "Google",
                                    "Chrome", "User Data", "Local State")

    with open(local_state_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        local_state = f.read()
        local_state = json.loads(local_state)

    key = base64.b64decode(local_state["os_crypt"]["encrypted_key"])
    key = key[5:]

    return win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(key, None, None, None, 0)[1]


def decrypt_password(password, key):
    try:
        iv = password[3:15]
        password = password[15:]
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)
        return cipher.decrypt(password)[:-16].decode()
    except:
        try:
            return str(win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(password, None, None, None, 0)[1])
        except:
            return ""


def get_chrome_datetime(chrome_date):
    return datetime(1601, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=chrome_date)


def main():
    key = get_encryption_key()
    db_path = os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"], "AppData", "Local",
                           "Google", "Chrome", "User Data", "default", "Login Data")

    filename = "ChromeData.db"
    shutil.copyfile(db_path, filename)

    db = sqlite3.connect(filename)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT origin_url, action_url, username_value,"
                   "password_value, date_created, date_last_used FROM logins ORDER BY date_created")

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        origin_url = row[0]
        action_url = row[1]
        username = row[2]
        password = decrypt_password(row[3], key)
        date_created = row[4]
        date_last_used = row[5]
        if username or password:
            print(f"Исходный URL-адрес: {origin_url}")
            print(f"URL действия: {action_url}")
            print(f"Имя пользователя: {username}")
            print(f"Пароль: {password}")
        else:
            continue

        if date_created != 86400000000 and date_created:
            print(f"Дата создания: {str(get_chrome_datetime(date_created))}")
        if date_last_used != 86400000000 and date_last_used:
            print(f"Последний визит: {str(get_chrome_datetime(date_last_used))}")

        print("-" * 50)

    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    try:
        os.remove(filename)
    except:
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Google didn't help.

Comment: _but the library still doesn't work._ what does that mean, exactly?

Comment: i suspect your pip is pointing to a different version of python ... try the following instead
`python -m pip install pywin32` then right after that finishes type `python myscript.py` ... by  using `python -m pip` you can be more sure which version of python you are using

Comment: this answer is to do with virtualenv, but same thing basically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68513540/how-to-install-and-run-virtualenv-on-macos-correctly/68513558#68513558