# While trying to install pyttsx3: Python 2.7 is no longer supported

Tags: python, pip, command

I am trying to install the pyttsx3 library, but i keep getting this error.
[error shown when trying to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPU2v.png)

I'm confused though because when I run "python --version" it does say im on version 2.7. But when i run "python3 --version" it says that im on 3.12. How would I stop my machine from trying to use the 2.7 version instead of the 3.12.

Also, I am using a Macbook on Monterrey.

I've tried installing it with pip3 instead of pip but that doesn't work either. I've also tried to update it but it doesn't seem to actually update it. I've also tried to delete it but that doesnt work either.

Comment: Try to use `python3 -m pip` instead of `pip`.  The `pip` command on your system defaults to the `python2` version.

Comment: I've tried that as well but then it gives me this error:
error: externally-managed-environment

With that it says to try brew install but that also gives an error:
Error: No formulae or casks found for pyttsx3.

Comment: You should then set up a virtualenv - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68513540/how-to-install-and-run-virtualenv-on-macos-correctly